# JavaFX TableView event gets triggered only once?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, java-8, javafx-8

I want to get the selected row from a JavaFX TableView. The weird thing is, when I click on a row once, the event gets triggerd but not a second or third time. Why? And is there an other way of handling this event (e.g. normal eventhandler with an @FXML annotation)?

```
public PersonController {

    private ObservableList<Person> personData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> personTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        personTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (personTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                        showPersonDetails(newValue);
                }
        });
    }

}
```

FXML

```
<TableView fx:id="personTable" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <columns>
      <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Vorname" />
      <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Nachname" />
    </columns>
     <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
    </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. I had to initialize the properties in my JPA domain class.
So instead of:

```
private IntegerProperty id;
```

You have to write:

```
private IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
```